# unable to start a private service in an android library

Tags: android, android-service, android-library

I would like to develop an android library with a hidden started service inside that should not be seen by the app developer that is using the library.

My problem is that I either can hide the service or can start the service.

To hide a class for app developers I only found the way by omitting "public" before `class MyService extends Service {...}` so I only get an instance inside the same package of the library.

For starting the service by `startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class))` it is needed to declare it in my library manifest.

But if the service class is not public the compiler says

> 'com.mydomain.MyService' is not public

Any ideas how I can achieve the hidden existance of the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to develop an android library with a hidden started service inside that should not be seen by the app developer that is using the library.

If by "service" you mean a subclass of `Service`, registered in the manifest via `<service>`, this is not possible. A `Service` needs to be `public`, with a `public` zero-argument constructor. It also needs the `<service>` element in the manifest. All of this can be seen by the app developer, either by examining your library or by examining the build output. This is important, as it is the app developer who is responsible for the app, including everything in the app, which includes your library and its service.